# How to pass dynamically created information into a new Activity [Android]

Tags: android, json, android-activity, linker, dynamic-data

I am using a method in which json and php are used to dynamically get information to fill a table. here is an example

```
TextView team = new TextView(this);
  team.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  team.setPadding(3, 3, 0, 3);
  team.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(80,
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  team.setText(json_data.getString("team"));
  team.setTag(json_data.getString("team"));
  tr.addView(team);
```

How  would I make it so each TextView is click-able and sends the Tag information to a new Activity?  How do I initialize the TextView team?

```
team.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
   //What goes in here???        
   }
});
```

My goal is for the user to be able to click on a team name and be sent to an activity where team information is given.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
team.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
   //What goes in here???        
     String teamTag = (String)v.getTag();
     Intent newIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
     newIntent.putExtra("teamName", teamTag);
     startActivity(newIntent);
   }
});
```

and in newActivity to read the tag, use this..

```
String teamTag = getIntent().getStringExtra("teamName");
```

Comment: why the two strings in getStringExtra("teamName", "defaultName");  What is the purpose of "defaultName"

Comment: if you don't find the extra with key teamName, defaultName is returned.

Comment: I get this error The method getStringExtra(String) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: sry it has only 1 argument, no default string.. i have edited my answer.